# Monogodb: update element of array of objects with criterias

Tags: java, mongodb, reactive, mongotemplate

I have this document:

```
{
  "id" : "001",
  "items" : {
    "persons" : [ 
        {
            "city" : "London",
            "color" : "red",
            "status" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "city" : "Paris",
            "color" : "blue",
            "status" : "0"
        }
     ],
    "animals" : [ 
        {
            "city" : "Luton",
            "color" : "red",
            "status" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "city" : "London",
            "color" : "red",
            "status" : "0"
        }
     ]
}
```

In java, or at least direcly in mongo, I need to update the status of persons and animals to a new value for each item in those arrays who meets the criteria of city and/or color from input.
*Status is obligatory, city and color are not obligatory.*

Ex:

input **city=London**, **color=red** and **status=9** will result in:

```
{
  "id" : "001",
  "items" : {
    "persons" : [ 
        {
            "city" : "London",
            "color" : "red",
            "status" : "9"
        }, 
        {
            "city" : "Paris",
            "color" : "blue",
            "status" : "0"
        }
     ],
    "animals" : [ 
        {
            "city" : "Luton",
            "color" : "red",
            "status" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "city" : "London",
            "color" : "red",
            "status" : "9"
        }
     ]
}
```

input **color=red** and **status=7** will result in:

```
{
  "id" : "001",
  "items" : {
    "persons" : [ 
        {
            "city" : "London",
            "color" : "red",
            "status" : "7"
        }, 
        {
            "city" : "Paris",
            "color" : "blue",
            "status" : "0"
        }
     ],
    "animals" : [ 
        {
            "city" : "Luton",
            "color" : "red",
            "status" : "7"
        }, 
        {
            "city" : "London",
            "color" : "red",
            "status" : "7"
        }
     ]
}
```

I tried a lot of things, but nothing works. If somebody can came with a solution is great, but I will be satisfied with a piece of advice to guide me to solve this matter.

Answer (score 1):

From your question i just understood that you want to update status of those 2 objects
`persons`, `animals` by criteria of `or`.

```
Query query = Query.query(new Criteria().orOperator(
               Criteria.where("items.persons.city").is("your value"),
                       Criteria.where("items.persons.color").is("your value"),
                       Criteria.where("items.animals.city").is("your value"),
                       Criteria.where("items.animals.color").is("your value")
       ));
       Update update = new Update().set("items.$.status", "9");
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "Your class name");
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you

```
{
$or: [
{
  "items.persons.color": "red"
},
{
  "items.animals.color": "red"
}
]
},
{
$set: {
"items.persons.$[elem].status": "7",
"items.animals.$[elem].status": "7"
}
},
{
 arrayFilters: [
{
  "elem.color": "red"
}
]
})
```

for only color
ex- https://mongoplayground.net/p/UTLAVWQ884V

for both color and city
ex- https://mongoplayground.net/p/qRdi2c1VDQg